# The required attribute in my form is ignored after inserting jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In my html page, I have a form with a series of fields that are marked as "required". If someone forgets to select an option and clicks submit, they are told they must complete the form. However, when I add the jquery hide() and show(), the required attribute is ignored and clicking on the button automatically shows the next div, regardless of whether or not the form has been filled out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

html/jquery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#ChatFormat").hide();
            //$("#QuestSubmit").bind(("click",function(){
            $("#QuestSubmit").click(function(){
                $("#ChatFormat").show();
                $("#QuestFormat").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="QuestFormat">
        <div id="menu">
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="container" id="chatbox">
            <form  id = "IntroQuest">
                <h4>Please take a moment to answer a few quick questions. &nbsp;&nbsp;Thank you.</h4>
                <h4>What is your gender?
                    <select id = "Gender" required>
                        <option value selected>-Select-</option>
                        <option value = "Male">Male</option>
                        <option value = "Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </h4>
                <h4>What is your ethnicity?
                    <select id = "Ethnicity" required>
                        <option value selected>-Select-</option>
                        <option value = "Caucasian">Caucasian</option>
                        <option value = "Hispanic/Latino">Hispanic / Latino</option>
                        <option value = "Asian">Asian</option>
                        <option value = "MiddleEastern">Middle Eastern</option>
                        <option value = "PacificIslander">Pacific Islander</option>
                        <option value = "NativeAmerican">Native American</option>
                        <option value = "Other">Other</option>
                    </select>

                <input class = "submitbutton" id = "QuestSubmit" type = "submit" value = "Begin Chat">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper" id="ChatFormat">
        <div id="menu">
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="container" id ="chatbox"></div>

        <form name="message" action="">

            <input id="input" class="bottom" name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
            <input class="submitbutton"  name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put some simple logic in there before you do your next step. See below.

http://jsfiddle.net/hSHaE/

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="QuestFormat">
        <div id="menu">
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="container" id="chatbox">
            <!-- You need to have this form actually do something or it will throw a "Please use POST request" error at the end -->
            <form  id = "IntroQuest"> 
                <h4>Please take a moment to answer a few quick questions. &nbsp;&nbsp;Thank you.</h4>
                <h4>What is your gender?
                    <select id = "Gender" required>
                        <option value = "" selected>-Select-</option>
                        <option value = "Male">Male</option>
                        <option value = "Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </h4>
                <h4>What is your ethnicity?
                    <select id = "Ethnicity" required>
                        <option value = "" selected>-Select-</option>
                        <option value = "Caucasian">Caucasian</option>
                        <option value = "Hispanic/Latino">Hispanic / Latino</option>
                        <option value = "Asian">Asian</option>
                        <option value = "MiddleEastern">Middle Eastern</option>
                        <option value = "PacificIslander">Pacific Islander</option>
                        <option value = "NativeAmerican">Native American</option>
                        <option value = "Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <span id="errorMessage" style="display:hidden;color:red"></span>
                <input class = "submitbutton" id = "QuestSubmit" type = "submit" value = "Begin Chat">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper" id="ChatFormat">
        <div id="menu">
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="container" id ="chatbox"></div>

        <form name="message" action="">

            <input id="input" class="bottom" name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
            <input class="submitbutton"  name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the jquery to go along with it:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#ChatFormat").hide();
            //$("#QuestSubmit").bind(("click",function(){
            $("#QuestSubmit").click(function(){
                if($("#Ethnicity").val() == "" || $("#Gender").val() == "")
                {
                    $("#errorMessage").html("Please fill out all fields and try again.").show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#errorMessage").hide();
                    $("#ChatFormat").show();
                    $("#QuestFormat").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Hope that helps.
If that did it for you, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: This works but: I actually have a few more questions in the form which I left out. When I put them all in to the if statement, as soon as I hit "begin chat", it flashes the next screen real quick and then goes back to the previous screen. With all selects -1 in the if statement, it works great!

Comment: Could you update the jsFiddle and post the link so I can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The `click` handler is irrelevant when it comes to the form. Currently your code says, when the element `#QuestSubmit` is clicked do something. Not, when the form `#IntroQuest` is submitted do something.

So you should be able to fix it by changing:

```
$("#QuestSubmit").click(function(){
```

to:

```
$("#IntroQuest").on("submit", function(){
```

Comment: @gotguts: Do you mind telling me where it went wrong? Because this method avoided having to list out each of the required fields (which defeats the point of using the required attribute), and still allowed the browser to provide the default error messages when the the fields were not filled in.

Comment: It worked as far as displaying the default error messages. However, where it failed was it still went back to the initial screen. It didn't seem to process the $("#QuestFormat").hide(); and $("#ChatFormat").show();.